# Wicket image component not found on page

Tags: java, wicket

I get the following problem when trying to display a list of items. For each item, I have to display an image which is dynamically loaded via a Wicket `WebResource`. The items are loaded step by step — 50 at a time — upon user scrolling, using an Ajax scroll.

> [ERROR] 2011-04-19 09:58:18,000 btpool0-1  org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.logRuntimeException (host=, request=, site=):
>   org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: component documentList:scroller:batchElem:666:content:item:3:batchItemContent:linkToPreview:imageThumbnail not found on page com.webapp.document.pages.DocumentListPage[id = 1]
>   listener interface = [RequestListenerInterface name=IResourceListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IResourceListener.onResourceRequested()]
>
> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.InvalidUrlException: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: component documentList:scroller:batchElem:666:content:item:3:batchItemContent:linkToPreview:imageThumbnail
>   not found on page com.webapp.document.pages.DocumentListPage[id = 1] listener interface = [RequestListenerInterface name=IResourceListener, method=public abstract void org.apache.wicket.IResourceListener.onResourceRequested()]
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycleProcessor.resolve(WebRequestCycleProcessor.java:262)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1310)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
>       at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:479)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByGuice$$51619816.CGLIB$doGet$6()
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByGuice$$51619816$$FastClassByGuice$$6d42bf5d.invoke()
>       at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:64)
>       at com.freiheit.monitoring.PerformanceMonitoringMethodInterceptor.invoke(PerformanceMonitoringMethodInterceptor.java:115)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback$InterceptedMethodInvocation.proceed(InterceptorStackCallback.java:64)
>       at com.google.inject.internal.InterceptorStackCallback.intercept(InterceptorStackCallback.java:44)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByGuice$$51619816.doGet()
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:312)
>       at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter$$EnhancerByGuice$$51619816.CGLIB$doFilter$4()

How can this problem be solved?

Here is the part of the code responsible for adding the image:

```
previewLink.add(createThumbnailSmall("imageThumbnail", documentModel));
```

in

```
createThumbnailSmall(final String id, final IModel<BaseDocument> documentModel) {
    // thumbnailResource is an object that contains the path of the image

    if (thumbnailResource != null) {
        final WebResource resource = getWebResource(thumbnailResource);
        final Image image = new Image(id, resource);
        return image;
    }
    return new InvisibleContainer(id);
}

WebResource getWebResource(final DocumentResource documentResource) {
    return new WebResource() {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
            return new BaseStreamResource(documentResource);
        }
    };
}
```

where `BaseStreamResource` is the following:

```
public class BaseStreamResource extends AbstractResourceStream {
    private InputStream      _fileInputStream = null;
    private DocumentResource _resource        = null;

    public BaseStreamResource(final DocumentResource documentResource) {
        _resource = documentResource;
    }

    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws ResourceStreamNotFoundException {
        if (_fileInputStream == null) {
            try {
                if (_resource == null) {
                    throw new ResourceStreamNotFoundException("Resource was null");
                }
                _fileInputStream = _resource.getFileInputStream();
            } catch (final ResourceNotAvailableException ex) {
                throw new ResourceStreamNotFoundException(ex);
            }
        }
        return _fileInputStream;
    }
```

In HTML:

```
<a wicket:id="linkToPreview" href="#">
<img wicket:id="imageThumbnail" alt="Attachment"></img></a>
```

Comment: It will help if you show some of the code involved in the loading of the images.

Comment: which url you use for ImageUrl ?

Comment: I have attached the code to the initial post

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @Flori! Our system contains a powerful, easy-to-use text/code formatter. Check out the overview [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help); that page is accessible by clicking on the brightly colored question mark icon at top right of every post entry/edit box. Please use the formatter for future posts, to make it easier for us to understand your issues and help you. I'll fix this one for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution solved the problem:
- extend WebResource class
- add extended class as a resource to application shared resources

Ex:

```
public class MyWebResource extends WebResource {
    final ValueMap map = new ValueMap();

    @Override
    public IResourceStream getResourceStream() {        
        String fileName = getFileName();
        File file = new File(basePath, fileName);

        if (!file.exists()) {
            LOG.error("File does not exist: " + file);
            throw new IllegalStateException("File does not exist: " + file);
        }       
        return new FileResourceStream(file);
    }           

    public final void addResource() {
        Application.get().getSharedResources().add(getClass().getName(), this);
    }

    protected String getFileName() {
        return getParameters().getString("id");
    }   

    public final String urlFor(final String fileName) {         
        final ResourceReference resourceReference = new ResourceReference(getClass().getName());        
        final String encodedValue = WicketURLEncoder.QUERY_INSTANCE.encode(fileName);
        map.add("id", encodedValue);
        final CharSequence result = RequestCycle.get().urlFor(resourceReference, map);       
        if (result == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The resource was not added! "
                + "In your Application class add the following line:"
                + "MyConcreteResource.INSTANCE.addResource()");
        }   

        String absoluteUrl = RequestUtils.toAbsolutePath(result.toString());        
        return absoluteUrl;     
    } 
}
```

In Application class, in init(), I have added MyWebResource to shared resources:

```
public void init() {
    ... 
    new MyWebResource().addResource();        
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code added hasn't really added any clues for me, but maybe I can help narrow it down a bit anyway.

The stacktrace includes a reference to `com.webapp.document.pages.DocumentListPage`, which is likely calling some of the code you've posted.  The error indicates a bad url, so debugging into that class, adding debug prints, and looking at the values of any field containing a url might be worthwhile.

It might even help to modify the code in `DocumentListPage` (maybe temporarily for debugging) to catch `org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.InvalidUrlException` and adding debugging prints specifically when the exception is caught.

This isn't really an answer, but it's too big for a comment, and maybe it'll help you get closer to an answer.