# How can I load images dynamically and quickly in Wicket? 

Tags: wicket

I am trying to load a lot of images at the same time, dynamically, using a Wicket `WebResource`. The problem is that it takes a lot of time to load them, and in some cases it takes more than a minute, and then I get the following error:

> org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.request.InvalidUrlException: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: After 1 minute the Pagemap null is still locked by: Thread[http-8443-2,5,main], giving up trying to get the page for path: 6:documentList:scroller:batchElem:11:content:item:7:cols:9:batchItemContent:linkToPreview:imageThumbnail
>     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebRequestCycleProcessor.resolve(WebRequestCycleProcessor.java:262)
>     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1310)
>     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)
>     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)

Does anyone know other solutions to load an image dynamically, in order to avoid the error?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714229/wicket-image-component-not-found-on-page

Answer (score 0):

You could put each of the images in an `AjaxLazyLoadPanel` which would then create many short requests to the server for each image.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it takes a lot of time to load them, and in some cases it takes more than a minute

You should certainly try to get the load to take less than a minute, so you don't get the pagemap lock exception and so that you don't keep your users waiting.

The timeout can be increased, (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353765/increase-the-lock-time-for-after-1-minute-the-pagemap-null-is-still-locked-exce) ) but that's not the best solution.

What is taking this much time?  Are you doing complex rendering of dynamic images?  Can you show code?

You're probably already aware of it, but there are [image examples](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/images/) that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Better use Wicket shared resources to deliver the image content.
I.e. something like:
in MyApp#init() mount the resource - mountSharedResource() for 1.4 or mountResource() for 1.5.
Then use ContextImage with url that points to the mounted resource + dynamic parameter with the image name/path.
The benefit is that Wicket shared resources are not synchronized as Wicket Pages.